# PyProj transformation from CA state plane coordinates to Lat, Long not as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, gis, latitude-longitude, pyproj

I am trying to use pyproj to transform the Calfornia State Plane Zone 5 X-Y coordinates to Latitude, Longitude.

For validation, I kniow that CA Zone 5 X-Y coordinates (6559361.78613, 1834842.95456) is the address 13422 Ankerton St, Bassett, CA. The Latitude, Longitude *should* be (34.0342403°, -118.0076074°).

```
inProj = Proj(init='epsg:2229')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
x1,y1 = x1,y1=6559361.78613, 1834842.95456
LONGITUDE,LATITUDE = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
print(LATITUDE,LONGITUDE)
```

However, the output is `(34.65142393815357°, -65.96879755500356°)`, which is somewhere in the Atlantic, far from California Zone 5.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to teach me how to find the meaning of 'epsg'? I am trying to convert from state plane US (2001 Massachusetts Mainland) to Lat&Lon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inProj = Proj(init='epsg:2229', preserve_units=True)
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
x1,y1 = x1,y1=la_df['X_COORDINATE'][0], la_df['Y_COORDINATE'][0]
LONGITUDE,LATITUDE = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
print(LATITUDE,LONGITUDE)
```

Turns out that pyproj assumes that you are working in meters. To keep using the Imperial system, you must include the option `preserve_units=True`.